# How do I access Swift's REPL?

Tags: swift

I would like to know how to do this from the CLI so that I can test out some codes without launching Xcode. I saw someone did this but I couldn't find a way to do this yet.

Comment: None of this is necessary anymore.  All you have to do now is open your terminal and type swift and hit enter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After installing the Xcode6 beta, do

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/

$ xcrun swift
```

is a Swift REPL

**EDITED:**

For XCode 6, use:

```
xcrun swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume to switch this back to the regular Xcode CLI, I just do `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` ?

Comment: Yes, this selects which xcrun, xcodebuild, cc and other command line compile tools location

Comment: One more stupid question: How do I exit the CLI?

Comment: :help inside REPL for help, :quit exits.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo ctrl+D also works to exit

Comment: Xcode 6.0.1, this doesn't appear to be supported for MacOX10.9? Got "<unknown>:0: error: the SDK 'MacOSX10.9.sdk' does not support Swift"

Comment: After the an update in XCode, you may need to run xcode-select again. With XCode 6, there is a new trick. See my edited answer

Answer (score 16):

To extend on @vinicius answer, you can also use it without changing your default Xcode by using:

```
DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ xcrun swift
```

The easiest way to do that will be to edit your .bashrc and append:

```
alias swift='DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ xcrun swift'
```

At that point you'll be able to run it just by typing `swift`

If you use a csh variant you'll need:

```
env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ xcrun swift
```

and create the alias with

```
alias swift 'env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/ xcrun swift'
```